# Table joins with PXDatabase SelectMulti

Tags: acumatica

*Disclaimer: I'm new to C# and Acumatica Framework*

I'm looking to implement a database slot however I need to pull data from joined tables. I'm using the `PXDatabase.SelectMulti` method from the snippet below however, I have been unable to get it to work with joins. I also can't seem to find any examples of the method with joined tables.

Is there a way to join tables with this method or perhaps another way to query the data?

```cs
public class DatabaseSlotsExample : IPrefetchable
{
  protected List<string> values = new List<string>(); // store your values here
  
  public static List<string> Values
  {
    get
    {
      //Get the values from the slot dynamically. By providing table name, you inform system when it should reset the slot.
      return PXDatabase.GetSlot<DatabaseSlotsExample>("SlotSuperKey", typeof(YourTable)).values;
    }
  }

  public void Prefetch()
  {
    //read database here
    foreach(PXDataRecord rec in PXDatabase.SelectMulti<YourTable>(
        new PXDataField<YourTable.tableField>(), //definition for fields that system should select
        new PXDataFieldValue<YourTable.tableKey>("Some Condition") //definition for restriction that you need to apply
      ))
    {
      //populate your collection from the database here
      values.Add(rec.GetString(0));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure whether it would work but could you try to use a projection? I mean YourTable above would be projection and you would do the join in the projection. Again ... not sure whether this would would work because I have never used SelectMulti with a projection myself.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you use BQL.Fluent as a reference, the BQL query is also simplified. See below used on Service Orders:

```
 foreach (PXResult<FSServiceOrder> res in 
 SelectFrom<FSServiceOrder>.
 InnerJoin<FSAppointment>.On<FSAppointment.soRefNbr.IsEqual<FSServiceOrder.refNbr>>.
 InnerJoin<FSWFStage>.On<FSWFStage.wFStageID.IsEqual<FSAppointment.wFStageID>>.
 InnerJoin<FSRoom>.On<FSRoom.roomID.IsEqual<FSServiceOrder.roomID>>.
 InnerJoin<FSEquipment>.On<FSEquipment.registrationNbr.IsEqual<FSRoom.descr>>.
 Where<FSServiceOrder.srvOrdType.IsEqual<P.AsString>.
     And<FSWFStage.wFStageCD.IsEqual<P.AsString>>>.
     View.Select(this, "TO", "SCHEDULED")
{
   FSServiceOrder fsServiceOrder = res.GetItem<FSServiceOrder>();
   FSAppointment fsAppointment = res.GetItem<FSAppointment>();
}
```

Then you can use the below to pull the specific table data: